# Rails - Where to add validation code? (Controller or Model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models

I'm new to Rails, and am following [this tutorial](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html)

I creates a simple model called HighScores.

I would like to customize this so that I can add a validation method for the score. I know there are shortcuts like validates_ that we can use, but for the purpose of learning, I'd like to write a method that ensures the score is between a certain range.

Where should the validate method go? In `models/high_score.rb` or in `controllers/high_scores_controllers.rb`? Or maybe in `/helpers/high_scores_helper.rb?

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that you're following the **Edge**rails guide, so it may not be strictly suited to you if you are using Rails 3.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Validation that the model has correct data should go in the model itself. This ensures that any future attempt to save the model's data will use this validation, regardless of the path taken.

```
models\high_score.rb
```

Also -- FWIW, the validates methods aren't short cuts, they are well tested code that you should embrace and use.

Comment: Thanks Jesse as well. The explanation of why it goes into the model makes sense now.

Comment: Now, if I was using my own method instead of Rails' built-in validate feature (for sake of example) would I put it in the model or in the helper?

Comment: model, still the model. Only put items in a helper that will help you present the data, not validate the data.

Comment: So then how do you "reject" data if it's invalid? For example, if the code was in my view, I could do something like `if data_is_valid (show my page as normal else redirect_to with an error message`... I'm not really sure how to accept/reject data from the model?

Comment: in your controller, you see code like https://gist.github.com/jwo/b65d0e50d06666c51137 --- the `save` method will return false if the model is invalid (rejected).

Comment: Thanks Jesse. So to clarify: I assume that any validation code -- whether I use the `validates` method of Rails, or my own custom method -- should make the model's `save` method return false. So then how would I make the `save` method return false? Should I manually declare a `def save` within the \models\high_scores.rb file that performs my custom validation? (Let's say it's a special case of validation that cannot be done via Rails' standard `validate` method.

Comment: Ricky -- save runs all validations. If any either return false or insert a record into the errors hash, it will return false and not save. This could prove very useful: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#common-validation-options

Comment: EXACTLY what I was looking for! :-) Thanks Jesse. FYI all, the section "6 Performing Custom Validations" is what I was trying to achieve. Talks about how to write custom methods for validations

Answer (score 4):

The validation should go in models.

Here is an example of a range validation:

```
validates :score, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0 }
validates :score, :numericality => { :less_than => 100 }
```

Comment: Thanks! Now just out of curiosity, I would like to create a method that does the validation. In my example I said to validate a range, but let's say I wanted to use some more complex criteria (e.g. make sure they are perfect squares, or something). Can you please provide an example of how I would implementation validation code via a method, just for my own learning purposes?